# Problem adding a number of students registered to a course (as a row) to a SELECT statement in POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I have a database of courses. I need to get a name, a a topic, a teacher, a duration and a number of students registered. I get the first four successfully, but not the last one.

Here is what my tables look like:

[courses table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcBQ0.png)

[journal table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEbsI.png)

[all tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OuMH.png)

That's the successful part for the first four:

```
SELECT c.name, t.topic_name AS topic, u.name || ' '|| u.surname AS TEACHER, ((c.end_date - c.start_date) / 7)::int AS duration
FROM public.course c 
RIGHT JOIN public.topic t ON  c.topic_id = t.topic_id 
RIGHT JOIN public.teacher_course tc ON  c.course_id = tc.course_id 
RIGHT JOIN public.user u ON tc.teacher_id = u.user_id 
WHERE u.role_id = 2;
```

Basically, to know the number of registered students per course, I only need to count records in the journal table for each course, but when I add
`count(j.id_record) AS students_registered`

it just breaks and asks me to group everything by and blah blah.
I'm confused about that. How to get this number correctly for each course?

Comment: Hi, you'll get better answers if you will supply a minimum reproducible example, perhaps using something like https://dbfiddle.uk/ to give your table structure and some sample data.    Images of data are difficult to work with.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please update your question and post table definition(s) (ddl) as text - **no images**.  (see [Why no images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Additionally post sample data, also as text, and the expected output of that data. [Here](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) is a good place to create text tables.  Run there then place results between lines containing only ```.

Comment: Since this is clearly homework you should spend a few minuets with [How to ask Homework Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: @belayer say I did have text data in this format https://i.imgur.com/sz8Po9X.png.  Could I use that directly somehow?  Or would I have to parse it, assuming I wanted to create a working sql to test against.

Comment: Your image appears to be the result Senseful Solutions or some other ANSI text generator.   Create 2 lines in your question both of which contain contain only **```** (on standard keyboard just left of 1). Then copy the text and paste in *between* those lines.